# Selenium google Chrome c# cant open https pages

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Tring to direct the selenium to a https page and nothing is happening the chrome browser is not directed to the url, if i give an http url it works.

Any help with this issue?:

this is my code:

```
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C://Users//boaz//Desktop//ChromeDriver");
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

when url beeing my https url, the browser stays in the page that its in and doest redirect to the url

Any help?

Comment: What URL's have you tried? Can you navigate to these pages manually in Chrome?

Comment: Yes I can, when i put the url strait in to chrome it navigates to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the answer provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774235/chromedriver-in-selenium-and-ssl-certificate)? I believe it is a browser security issue with HTTPS and Certificates, so ignoring these errors may solve the issue (or provide a cert on the testing machine). Many people have this issue with Firefox because of user profiles I have heard too (I myself am forced to test in IE =[).