# Add ssl certificate to selenium-webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate, browsermob-proxy

I use selenium for end-to-end test with chromeDriver. The websites to test require an ssl certificate. When I manually open the browser, there is a popup that lets me select an installed certificate. Different tests access different URLs and also need different certificates. However, if I run the tests in headless mode, there is no popup. So I need a way to programatically set a certificate (eg. set a `.pem` file) to be used for the current test.

How can I achieve this?
I tried setting up a [browserMob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) proxy which I then configured as a proxy in selenium - however, this does not seem to do anything... Are there better approaches? What am I doing wrong? Here's what I tried:

```java
PemFileCertificateSource pemFileCertificateSource = new PemFileCertificateSource(
        new File("myCertificate.pem"),
        new File("myPrivateKey.pem"),
        "myPrivateKeyPassword");

ImpersonatingMitmManager mitmManager = ImpersonatingMitmManager.builder()
        .rootCertificateSource(pemFileCertificateSource)
        .build();

BrowserMobProxy browserMobProxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
browserMobProxy.setTrustAllServers(true);
browserMobProxy.setMitmManager(mitmManager);

browserMobProxy.start(8080);


ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setProxy(ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(browserMobProxy));

WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

// use the webdriver for tests, e.g. assertEquals("foo", webDriver.findElement(...))
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/6774235/3141682

Comment: @AdiOhana I already searched SO quite extensively... The person in this link just describes how to avoid the untrusted certificate error - this is not what I want, I need to programatically set a certificate to be used.

Comment: right, but one of the answers is describing: "You can tell the Chrome browser to use a specific client certificate for a particual URL by adding a registry KEY with the following content:" is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not really... Feels a bit dirty to make changes to the registry for each test. Also, at some point I would like to run these tests in docker containers, so this won't be possible anymore.

Comment: It would be possible to run in docker containers if you create a new driver (and browser) for each of your test cases with the desired certificate according to your website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So apparantly this is not possible with BrowserMob out of the box. I therefore wrote a proxy extension `SeleniumSslProxy` that can be plugged into Selenium and adds certificate based authentication to create a HTTPS connection.

This is how it works:

- intercept Selenium HTTP requests with BrowserMob
- setup an `SSLContext` given a certificate (.pfx file) and password
- use [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) to forward the request to the target URL
- convert the okhttp `Response` to a netty `FullHttpResponse` so it can be handled by Selenium

You can find the code on [github](https://github.com/patricsteiner/seleniumSslProxy). Here's an example how it can be used in Selenium end-to-end tests (also works in headless mode):

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    File clientSslCertificate = new File(
        classLoader.getResource("certificates/some-certificate.pfx").getFile());
    String certificatePassword = "superSecret";

    this.proxy = new SeleniumSslProxy(clientSslCertificate, certificatePassword);
    this.proxy.start();

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setProxy(proxy);
    this.webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
}

@Test
public void pageTitleIsFoo() {
    // given
    String url = "http://myurl.lol";
    // NOTE: do not use https in the URL here. It will be converted to https by the proxy.

    // when
    this.webDriver.get(url);
    this.webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, SECONDS);

    // then
    WebElement title = this.webDriver.findElement(By.className("title"));
    assertEquals("Foo", title.getText());
}

@After
public void teardown() {
    this.webDriver.quit();
    this.proxy.stop();
}
```

Note that I only used chromeDriver and never tested it with other drivers. Minor adjustments to the `SeleniumSslProxy` might be necessary to be used with other drivers.