# Session.desiredCapabilities are ignored by Session.negotiatedCapabilities when running PhantomJSDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless-browser, ghostdriver

I have a requirement where I need to run test scenarios of validating my webpage in Amazon linux2 instance without any GUI. Hence I selected PhantomJS/GhostDriver to perform these executions.
I also need to add valid certificate in my driver for running tests.

**Part of the code when setting Desired capabilities and initiating my PhantomJS driver.**

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        capabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "phantomjs");
        try {
            final String webSecurity = "--web-security=false";
            final String sslProtocol = "--ssl-protocol=any";
            final String ignoreSSLErrors = "--ignore-ssl-errors=true";
            final String webDriverLogLevel = "--webdriver-loglevel=DEBUG";
            final String clientCertFile = "--ssl-client-certificate-file=" + clientCertificateAbsolutePath;
            final String clientKeyFile = "--ssl-client-key-file=" + clientSecretKeyAbsolutePath;
            final String clientKeyPassphrase = "--ssl-client-key-passphrase=" + passPhrase;
            String[] params = new String[]{webSecurity, sslProtocol, ignoreSSLErrors, webDriverLogLevel, clientCertFile, clientKeyFile, clientKeyPassphrase};
            String phantomJSPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            logger.info("Path for PhantomJS file:" + phantomJSPath);              capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,  "/usr/bin/phantomjs");
            capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,params);
            WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

When test is being executed, I am noticing that **desiredCapabilities** are being ignored and replaced by **negotiatedCapabilities** and hence the Cert details are being invalidated when headless browser is rendered.
[image]

Can anyone please suggest how it can be resolved or any better way or approach for running my tests.